# Magento 2.3 images cache generation generates wrong hash for some images with a custom theme

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.0

I just upgrade my Magento 2 project from 2.2.6 to 2.3. After the upgrade, some images in the catalog are showing placeholders instead of the images. I have regenerated the images cache with the catalog:images:resize but some images are still missing (swatch images in category pages and image thumbnail in category pages).

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19710

Comment: Same issue here with 2.3.1 - Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: No ... somw how  write script for same and it worked after resize all image